# Is it possible to use an xml file containing test results from a pipeline as input to an Azure Dashboard to display the results in this XML file?

Tags: azure-devops, saucelabs

we are running some tests using saucelabs , the pipeline connects to sauce labs runs the tests and then generates a xml file of the results on the build machine. Is there a way we can use this xml file as input into an Azure Devops Dashboard to display the results of the tests run via the pipeline?

Comment: I would try to use `PublishTestResults` task. You should indicate your .xml. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Cyaml. You can then use a Test results widget on the dashboard to have a view

Comment: i will try that